# Case statement result to another case

Tags: sql, case

I need to combine below logic and put it in a sql statement.

Logic:

```
CASE WHEN (ABC = 2)
        THEN  0
        ELSE  1
END XYZ

IF XYZ > 1
THEN 
FINAL_COLUMN = 10
ELSE 
FINAL_COLUMN = 20
```

SQL :

```
select (CASE WHEN(CASE ABC=2 then 0 Else 1 END AS) XYZ >123 
Then 10 ELSE 100 ) END AS FINAL_COLUMN  
from Table 1;
```

Comment: *And the question is...?*

Comment: You do realize that XYZ is 0 or 1, which is never >1, right?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for the case statement is

```
 Case 
     When Condition1 Then Value
     When Condition2 Then Value2
     Else Value
 End
```

So your statement should look like

```
 Select CASE WHEN ABC = 2 Then 0 Else 1 End AS FINAL_COLUMN  from Table 1;
```